# Passing indexer as argument in C#

Tags: c#, properties, parameter-passing, ref, indexer

When I pass indexer as argument by reference there is compile time error in code.

1. Why indexers can’t be passed with ref or out keywords?

> 2. What is the mechanism of allocation memory to the fields that is encapsulated by indexer (when we set any values to an element of indexer of class Defining_Indexer)?

```
     using System;

    class Defining_Indexer

    {
        private string LanguageUser;
        //Declaring indexer
        public string this[int index]
        {
    get
    {
        return LanguageUser;
    }
    set
    {
        LanguageUser = value;
    }
        }
    }
    class Using_Indexer{

        //Declaring a method that will use indexer as argument
        public static string BestLanguage(ref string name)
        {


    //Here I want to show number of users of best language.
        Console.WriteLine("Number of user : ");
        //I want to modify the number of user Since parameter is initialized then best language 
        //users number is decided so there is no any fake.
        string declare = name + "2000";
        Console.WriteLine(declare);
        return declare;
    }//end of BestLanguage Method
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Defining_Indexer result = new Defining_Indexer();
        //Here result elememts store the number of users of a some language.
        result[0] = "2315";//C
        result[1] = "4500";//C++
        result[2] = "44000";//C#
        BestLanguage(ref result[2]);//--Here is error
        Console.Write("Number of User by Main Method :");
        Console.WriteLine(result[2]);
    }
    }
```

This is compile-time-error

> A property or indexer may not be passed as an ref or out parameter.

Comment: Properties and indexers are just functions behind the scenes. You cannot obtain references to them the same way as regular fields or variables.

Answer (score 5):

> Why indexers can’t be passed with ref or out keywords?

Because indexers are effectively *methods*.  It's not necessarily a *variable* with an address in memory that you can pass a "reference" to.

The way to do it is to use a temporary local variable instead:

```
result[2] = "44000";//C#
string temp = result[2];
BestLanguage(ref temp);
result[2] = temp;
```

However I would note that your method *is not modifying the reference*, so there's no need to make it a `ref` parameter at all!

Answer (score 1):

1. Indexers and properties are syntactic sugar for functions.
2. Not sure I fully understand the question, but it sounds like you're asking how the indexer separates the stored values into different memory based on the index value. Short answer: it doesn't. You have to do that yourself in the set and get functions.

The way your indexer is currently implemented, no matter what result[x] you use, you will overwrite `LanguageUser`.